# How can I make the distro version auto install if greater than certain amount

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have this shell script which will check for linux distro with version id.

```
  if [ -e /etc/os-release ]; then
    source /etc/os-release
    DISTRO=$ID
    DISTRO_VERSION=$VERSION_ID
  fi
```

Distro:

```
    if [ "$DISTRO" == "ubuntu" ] && ([ "$DISTRO_VERSION" == "20.04" ] || [ "$DISTRO_VERSION" == "19.10" ]); then
      apt-get install netdata
    fi
```

Another Script

```
    if [ "$DISTRO" == "ubuntu" ] && ([ "$DISTRO_VERSION" == "16.04" ] || [ "$DISTRO_VERSION" == "18.04" ]); then
      apt-get install unzip
    fi
```

How do I turn this from adding new DISTRO_VERSION for every release to something like

```
if DISTRO = ubuntu && => 19.10 than 
apt-get install netdata
fi
```

and

```
if DISTRO = ubuntu && <= 19.10 than 
apt-get install unzip
fi
```

The point is I don't want to keep adding distro version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux basic automation is often solved with cron jobs but in this case in Debian and consequently Ubuntu there is an "unattended-upgrades" functionality that help you manage this.

You can  more about it in the links below:

1. [Debian Unattended Upgrades](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)
2. [Ubuntu Unattended Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates#Using_the_.22unattended-upgrades.22_package)
3. [Previously answered Ask Ubuntu SO question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/923535/schedule-apt-get-script-using-cron)
4. [Kali tut guide](https://www.kalitut.com/2017/11/automatically-install-security-updates.html)

Comment: No.https://github.com/complexorganizations/wireguard-manager its for this, what your saying wont work and `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get update` is just an example